# Gerar código alfanumérico aleatório de 10 caracteres

Tags: java, android

Tenho hoje uma aplicação que está apresentando divergência de dados por causa do tempo de retorno de um webservice.

Para contornar isso criamos um código para impedir que essa determinada informação nunca se repita, até ai tudo certo está funcionando.

Eu preciso de gerar um código de identificação de 10 dígitos, que não se repita em outros tablets que usam a minha aplicação. Pois pode comprometer os dados no sistema.

Como posso gerar um código alfanumérico aleatório com 10 dígitos e que esse mesmo código não se repita, usando o Java?

Comment: Porque não usa o `UUID` do dispositivo?

Comment: cada hora que eu gero uma informação, no caso uma ordem de serviço eu preciso de um código diferente.

Comment: Ainda que sejam 10 dígitos aleatórios, exite a chance do dispositivo A e B gerarem o mesmo.  A ideia do @Wakim resolveria seu problema, porque essa `UUID`  é única, eu acho.

Comment: Já que para cada requisição precisa ser único, poderia salgar o `UUID` com um `timestamp` e gerar um MD5. o MD5 pode ser opcional acredito.

Comment: Sim eu pensei nisso, porém o serviço só aceita até 10 caracteres nesse local.

Comment: Agora pensando aqui, se eu gerar o MD5 e dar quebrar a string em até 10 caracteres funcionaria.

Comment: Acho que fazer substring de MD5 não é uma boa solução, porque prefixos podem se repetir, até mesmo MD5 tem colisões. Eu vi que existe o `ANDROID_ID` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID), que é um número de 64 bits, que é único para cada usuário/dispositivo.

Comment: @Wakim obrigado, se quiser colocar como resposta para eu marcar como correta. Ai você complementa para pegar o timestamp o uuid e gerar o md5 e pegar só as 10 primeiras posições da String retornada.

Comment: @HiagoSouza, não recomendo usar substring no `MD5`. O `MD5` já tem uma certa probabilidade de colisão, usar substring vai aumentar bastante (colisão ocorre quando duas valores geram o mesmo hash). O jeito é procurar uma algoritmo de encriptação que possa gerar exatamente 10 dígitos, afim de não aumentar as colisões.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o **UUID** e deixar 2 dígitos para você ir incrementando a cada operação, assim você nunca repete. Deixa um *length* disponível, que você acredita que não vá estourar.

Outra possibilidade é utilizar um número fixo de cada aparelho e os segundos do dia que em que você estiver usando em alfanumérico, por exemplo 00:02 da manha da 120seg 003c no caso 4 dígitos.

Comment: Eu acho que é uma boa resposta, e não um comentário. Como o UUID tem 8 caracteres, sobram 2 pros IDs, ou seja, 65536 transações, sem nenhum risco de repetição. Acho que é uma excelente solução.

Comment: Só falta fazer ajustes na gramática para ser uma resposta razoável. Você pode [edit] a pergunta para ficar em boas condições.

Comment: Vou almoçar mais tarde efetuo os testes..